# Adjust Digital Vibrance or Saturation in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, display

How do you adjust the digital vibrance or color saturation in Ubuntu 18.04

The graphics driver installed in my machine is `amdgpu-pro-19.30-855429-ubuntu-18.04`

AFAIK there's no GUI for the latest AMD drivers but is there a way to adjust saturation using scripts or similar?